# Certain errors running ScriptRunner3 on QGIS 2.99 (classFactory() method)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I have been trying to learn QGIS and I've been tasked to start with QGIS 3 so I have been going through Gary Sherman's PyQGIS Programmer's Guide.

I am currently using QGIS 2.99.0-Master, running Python 3.6.4, and am working with Script Runner 3.0.3.

I also have QGIS 2.18.15 which has Script Runner working fine. (I was midway going through an earlier edition (for QGIS 2.0) of the same guidebook before I got the newer one (for QGIS 3), which I then switched to.)

I have been trying to install ScriptRunner3 using QGIS's own plugin installer, but I keep getting some this error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'scriptrunner3' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 336, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/zkang/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\scriptrunner3\__init__.py", line 24, in classFactory
    from .scriptrunner import ScriptRunner
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/zkang/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\scriptrunner3\scriptrunner.py", line 27, in 
    import win32api
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 664, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Python version: 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 
QGIS version: 2.99.0-Master Master, b6ad920404 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python
C:/Users/zkang/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/zkang/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2.99/apps/qgis-dev/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS2.99\bin\python36.zip
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2.99\apps\Python36\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2.99\apps\Python36\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS2.99\bin
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2.99\apps\Python36
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2.99\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages
C:/Users/zkang/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

It might be worth to note that there was a previous error, where QGIS could not find `win32.api` (despite me having installed it already) and I had to append the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to get around that. So the error at hand might just be very bad installation on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The win32api module isn't included with python3 or with the QGIS installer.

You can install it using:

```
python3 -m pip install pywin32
```

If you need help setting up your command line environment on windows, see:
http://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis3-on-windows

I've added a warning about the requirement in the latest version (3.0.4).

Comment: Version 3.0.5 of ScriptRunner attempts to do the install for you if win32api is missing.